# Light weight graph and gauge library in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, gauge

I am looking for a light weight **chart and gauge library** in java script to design web pages
of an embedded product.

I searched in Google but many were heavy and some libraries were needed be downloaded at run time.
Since mine is an embedded device I need a small size js library.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what kind of charts and gauges you need, and also indicate which libraries you rejected as "too heavy"?  If you have a specific size limit, please say what it is.

Comment: I need to display mainly bar, line chart and meter gauge. I am not expecting graphic rich widgets but the size of the library should be less than 100 kb. high charts, google charts are some of them which I rejected because of the size limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice Jquery based guage (no chart features). Free, which is a nice feature:

http://www.justgage.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) is lightweight library.

Comment: This *is* a valid answer to the question, but it would be better if you described the suggested library a bit more and explained why it would be a good fit.

Comment: I think the link explains it more accurately than me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try www.jqchart.com charts and gauges.
They are really lightweight and functional.

Disclaimer: I work for JQChart.

Best,
Maxim Milev

Comment: I am looking for open source library.

Comment: @MaximMilev I am using jqplot to render meter gauges. Could you help me whether I can change the default image of MeterGauge to something else